# What are the criteria(in the programming point of view) that one should keep in mind while creating a java jar(as library) file for android

Tags: java, android, jar, coding-style, standards

I know how to create a jar file using Eclipse.

I was trying to create a share library so that I can avoid redundant source code. I have figured out that a jar should be :-

- independent
- should not make call to external class attributes(properties)/methods except the standard library imports.
- The resources should be given as a parameter to jar file to perform a action.
- Should work as a independent entity.

I tried to well organised my code in different packages also added MANIFEST.MF file.

This is first time I'm trying for data abstraction.

I would like to request suggestions/instructions as per the programmer point of view, what are the criteria that jar code should have ?

Is it good idea that my jar is or depend on another jar (viz java mail api jar) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you've tagged this with Android, I assume that Android is the intended use case.

The easiest way to share your code between several projects is probably to create a library project, this way you can keep the source code at hand too (less convenient to attach source to the jar every time you use it).